# How to measure and sample oscillations in a LC tank using a Microcontroller

Tags: adc, sampling, oscillation

Since the oscillations in a LC tank starts with high amplitudes and dies gradually, and since the first oscillations are to some extent unpredictable in amplitude, how can one measure and sample such wave using MCU and/or ADC components?

I need to sample the oscillating wave (which oscillates between 10-500 kHz from a seldom pulsed LC tank) until it dies out, with 1 MHz sampling rate.

But I don't know how to convert the high voltages in the LC circuit, to MCU-safe voltages.
using voltage dividers will do the job, but it attenuates the whole wave, so though it's useful in reducing the first high voltage spikes, it makes the resolution (precision?) decrease later as the wave continues to oscillate in very lower amplitudes. (since there's a limited ADC resolution after all, and sampling is done continuously as long as the amplitude is above 100 mV).
Actually only the samples which are from the amplitudes of ~5 V or lower are important to me, and only that portion of dataset will be analyzed. so if the first portion of wave is bypassed totally, it'll still be ok.

[image: Damped-Oscillation]

1. Is it possible to truncate this wave into the 5 V values shown (to be
   safe to be fed to ADC of a 5 V MCU)?
2. or is it possible to kinda bypass the voltage divider resistors
   after the amplitude goes below 5 V?
3. any suggestion for better methods on how to sample such waves (very dynamic in the amplitude) is welcomed.

Comment: Why you want sample 500kHz with 1MHz sample rate? If you are interrested about frequency of oscillation use analog comparator. Regarding voltage clamp most of MCUs have protection diodes on pins so just connect the signal source through 1k resistor to pin.

Comment: I need to measure the time it takes for the wave to reach 100mV amplitude. that's why I need to be precise in time. (i.e. I need to find the value of Te as precisely as my components allow)

Comment: Then just rectify the signal to cap with sufficient load to get “outer contour” of oscillations so you don’t have to bother with high frequencies.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Thanks, I don't wanna be a burden to those who answer questions or guide me. but please mention as many keywords so I can search them and be able to understand your suggestion. I searched for "outer contour of oscillation" and couldn't understand what's it about, I think I need to read some other basic concepts. throw keywords, subjects at me or any related concept I need to read about.

Comment: It’s called “envelope decay” and damped oscillations creates an exponential function.

Comment: The rectification can be done using op-amp. Look for op-amp as a rectifier.

Comment: ADC sampler of one million samples/sec is a serious limitation for a 500 kHz waveform. The required dynamic range spanning 100V to 100mV is another limitation. Acquiring sampled waveforms from a **digital oscilloscope** might be a simpler alternative. Although many 'scopes have 8-bit resolution, you can set gain, sampling as you wish, to more closely examine sections of an input wave.

Comment: I don't need to recreate the waveform, there are a few statistical analysis I wanna perform on the sampled data. most vital one of them is a precise-enough time that amplitude has reached the 100mV value. (Te in the image). others are average absolute amplitude over a few sections of time before the moment of Te.

Comment: What starts the oscillation?

Comment: @Bikay So if you only need to know anything about when the signal is near 100 mV, you should clamp anything outside the range of approximately ±500 mV, apply a gain of 5 and shift up by +2.5 V, and you can just measure the signal directly in its new zero to 5 V range.

Comment: @Hearth the oscillation gets started by a 24V (or 36V) square pulse to the coil. so the whole oscillation is a damping back-EMI from the coil flux collapsing.